# while installing php driver for mongodb for xampp on osx ERROR: `phpize' failed

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, driver

I installed mongodb with brew.
while installing php driver for mongodb for xampp on osx

I used This command: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo

> ERROR: `phpize' failed

Full error in terminal

```
WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb"
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading mongo-1.6.12.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.6.12.tgz (209,252 bytes)
.............................................done: 209,252 bytes
118 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Comment: I used This command : sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution: and it worked for me.

1. **Download autoconf** 
   `curl http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz > autoconf.tar.gz`
2. **Untar the autoconf archive**
   `tar -xvzf autoconf.tar.gz`
3. **Configure and make – note the folder un-archived may have a different name.**

   `cd autoconf-2.69`

   `./configure`

   `sudo make && sudo make install`
4. **This installs autoconf to ‘/usr/local/bin/autoconf’. In order to get phpize to work set the PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable to point to the newly installed autoconf.**
   `export PHP_AUTOCONF=/usr/local/bin/autoconf`